# Remove scale from chart.js

Tags: javascript

[image]

I want to remove white scale in middle of radar chart from chart.js

Comment: That's nice. I'd like a new house myself, but to each their own. =)

Comment: Seriously though, please read [ask], and include a [mcve] _in your question_.

Comment: no you can't. your machine will blow up... Seriously, this is not a "do-this-for-me" site.. include your code so that we can help you find your mistakes and give suggestions, etc.

Comment: Geoman Yabes it is chart.js plugin I am simply asking to remove(hide that white scale). I have not written any other code. and I have tried all possible options{} but still no result.

Answer (score 4):

try adding this to your chart options:

```
options: {
    scale: {            
        ticks: {
            display: false
        }
    }
}
```

couldn't find this in the docs anywhere [http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest], but it seems that when you use a polar chart, as opposed to using the `scales` property, it's just `scale` (singular) and no `xAxes` or `yAxes` needed.

sorry for the late reply... hope this is still of use to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Try `scaleShowLabels:false` it should work

Comment: @Nitesh Yadav options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                display: false
            }
        }]
    }
    }

Comment: Will look for something more later. I thoight the last one worked. Sorry

Comment: @JustARandomProgrammer i appreciate your answer and thank you so much for answering my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

In Angular **ng2-chart** (Which internally used **Chart.js** )

We can use

**public lineChartLegend = false;** (For Scale labels/legends to hide)

**Stackblitz Link:-**
https://stackblitz.com/github/santam85/ng2-charts-line-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html&preset=node

**Attached screenshot:-**
[image]